# How to get uislider pointing area?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uislider

I have uislider with 6 tabs at the top please see the [image].

Now i want to get the tab at which the slider is pointing. if we move the slider.

All the tabs can be rearraged by dragging and placing them so if tab1 moves to position of tab5 and slider is at tab5 (second last position)which is new position for tab1 it should show tab1 values not tab5 values.

```
- (void)addTab:(UIViewController *)viewController {
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(willShowTab:)]) {
    [self.delegate willShowTab:viewController];
}

if (![self.childViewControllers containsObject:viewController] && self.count < self.maxCount - 1) {
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];
    viewController.view.frame = _contentFrame;

    if (_toobarVisible)
        [self.toolbar setItems:viewController.toolbarItems animated:YES];

    // Add tab selects automatically the new tab
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                      duration:kAddTabDuration
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
                    animations:^{
                        [self.tabsView addTab:viewController.title];

                        if (self.currentViewController) {
                            [self.currentViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];
                            [self.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                            [self.currentViewController viewDidDisappear:YES];
                        }

                        [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                        _currentViewController = viewController;
                    }];
}
```

}

Please provide me snippet code.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Comment: If you wish for the slider to remain accurate after rearranging the tabs, it'll require a little more than a "snippet" to get the job done.

Comment: i want the slider to be at its position where it is ...on the other hand when i rearrange the tabs, the tab at which slider points should display its value

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, if all of your tabs are the same width, then you just need to figure out which section of the total width the slider is currently positioned at, and select the tab at that index.  Otherwise, you would have to iterate through the tabs to find their horizontal bounds to figure out which one the slider is selecting

Comment: Same width is OK but all the tabs are movable so if one tab moves to other position how do i know at which tab the slider is positioned at ? Please provide me snippet

Comment: How you know which tab is at which index is entirely dependent on how you're storing the tabs

Comment: so all of the tabs are stored in the toolbar?  It is very difficult to tell, your code is difficult for me to read

Comment: Thanks Dan... not an issue if you get time or get an idea please share here